# Scoping problems in different shell languages?

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

It appears that pdksh and mksh has the scoping implementation I expected.

For example:

```
readonly x='global'

f() {
  local x
  readonly x='f'
  echo $x
}

g() {
  local x
  readonly x='g'
  echo $x
}

echo $x

f 
g

echo $x
```

pdksh and mksh produce my expected result:

```
global
f
g
global
```

And Bash fails:

```
line 5: local: x: readonly variable
```

Dash and Ksh93 failed my expect, too.  (I've changed `local` to `typeset` in Ksh93's test.)

This seems confusing.

UPDATE: I've edited the question.  The question before is not stated in a clear way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash and Dash don't fail if the global variable is not read only.

Korn (ksh93) doesn't fail only if *none* of the instances of `x` are read only.

Comment: There's a [recent discussion](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2011-02/msg00105.html) of this topic on the gnu.bash.bug mailing list.