# BASH bug or feature?: Shadowing a readonly global variable with a writable local variable

Tags: bash, variables, scope, readonly-variable

(Possibly this is the same question as [Function local read-only vs. global read-only variable with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5038803/6607497))

In a script I wrote I'm using `readonly key="$1"` (for the program parameter) at the global level, and a function uses `local key="$1"` (for the function parameter this time), too.

To my surprise BASH 4.4 outputs:

> ...: local: key: readonly variable

In my understanding there is a *global* readonly variable, but the `local` variable should be independent of it, even when having the same name, right?

Or did I misunderstand something?
Reading the manual page on `local` did not bring me any further.
Or is it that `local` does *not* declare a *local variable*, but a *local value* for a (global) variable (thus the global read-only status preventing even a local change)?

Would be a rather confusing concept then IMHO.

Comment: This is by design, variables classified as `readonly`, can't be redefined in _any_ scope

Comment: see discussions in bash mail list: [this](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2011-02/msg00105.html) (2011) and [this](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2019-03/msg00150.html) (2019).

Comment: @Inian However it's different from practically all languages I know.

Comment: So it seems (as I suspected) that `local` does **not** declare or define a (new) *local variable*, but instead if defines a "local value" for a variable that may exist already. However if such variable exists as read-only, such "local value" is not possible per design. An odd and unexpected concept, but probably the way it is implemented (and generally accepted).